# Changing Mac Keychain Password Programmatically?

Tags: macos, keychain

I'm using Mac 10.5.8; can any one tell me if there is any way to update the keychain's password programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the master-password of keychain itself or the password for an application stored in keychain?